# Get element id from extern Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an extern form from API display in a modal. I want to close the modal when it's submitted.

My modal

```
<div id="modal">
  <div class="modalconent">
    <div class="pipedriveWebForms" data-pd-webforms="https://pipedrivewebforms.com/form/f5cd01e9418f0b683195eb0e821770181945719">
    </div>
    <button id="button">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

My script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById(submitButtonLoading).onclick = function () {
      document.getElementById('modal').style.display = "none"
    };
  };
</script>
<script src="https://pipedrivewebforms.com/webforms.min.js"></script>
```

I can't modify the form from the API. When I inspect it in my web browser I see the submit button has the id `submitButton`. But, my function doesn't work with this id. I don't know how to make my modal work with the API script.

Comment: Is `submitButtonLoading` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing I can see is your getElementById(submitButtonLoading) doesn't have doesn't have quotes around it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById('submitButtonLoading').onclick = function () {
      document.getElementById('modal').style.display = "none"
  };
};
</script>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As Leo said, you are missing quotes in

```
document.getElementById(submitButtonLoading).
```

But it calls for an element with id = "submitButtonLoading" and you don't have it as I see from your code that you ided as "button"

```
<button id="button">Close</button>
```

Change it to:

```
<button id="submitButtonLoading">Close</button>
```

Comment: I tried with quotes but it doesnt work, and i the close button is to my tests i want force customers to complete the form before have access to the result page

Comment: You mean the button with the id="submitButtonLoading" is for test purposes or the one with id="button"?

Comment: the one with id "button" is for test

Comment: i tried with submitbutton id but it doesnt work, i think its because the button from JS API

Comment: Could you try document.queryselector with  pipedriveWebForms? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: I tried   document.querySelector('pipedriveWebForms').onclick = function, but it doesnt work its like i dont have control on the form

Comment: What could work is to write a listener for clicks on the page, like element.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("Hello World!"); });

on the above named button or event the form.